# Swift 3 & JSON – How to edit data received from the database?

Tags: json, swift, database

This is a simple question of how-to. I don't know (and can't figure out on my own) what the correct terminology is for "editing" the data received from the JSON code. Here's my current code:

```
// Create a url and a session to load it in the background.
let url = URL(string: "http://api.fixer.io/latest")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

    if error == nil {

        // Try to extract some content from the data.
        if let content = data {
            do {

                // Try to create an array out of the extracted data content.
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                // Search for specific objects in the array.
                if let rates = jsonResult["rates"] as? NSDictionary {
                    print("Rates: \(rates)\n\n")
                    if let currency = rates["USD"] {
                        // Output of line below is – "Currency: \"1.0893\""
                        print("Currency: \(currency)")
                    }

                }

            } catch {
                print("Error deserializing the JSON:\n\(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }

    } else {
        print("Error creating the URLSession:\n\(String(describing: error))")
    }

}

// Begin using the URLSession to extract the data.
task.resume()
```

As you can see above, I am getting some data from a url using JSON, and then extracting a specific set of data which I'm titling `rates` and `currency`.

However, I can't find anywhere on the web for how to edit data. For example: let's say I want to change the value of `currency` to be equal to "$230" instead of "1.0893." What is the term/code necessary to go in and change that? Another example would be if I wanted to **add** another object into the `rates` Dictionary. What if I wanted to add `"MyCurrency: true"`, or something like that? I'm not knowledgeable of the specific syntax on this. I need help!

EDIT – Yes, I am trying to change the database itself, that way when the information is pulled from it later on, it is updated with the changes I make now. In my above example, I said I could change `currency` to "$230." Well, I want it to permanently stay that way in the database, so that when I extract its value later, instead of still being "1.0893," it's now the value I changed it to.

Is this term "pushing?" I would like to make changes to the database itself.

Comment: If you're getting your data from a URL, you're going to need to post the modified data back to another URL to tell the database to update. You'll probably serialize the data back to JSON and use another `URLSession` to post it, but the specifics of where you send it and how you format it will depend on the database you're trying to modify, its web API, and your level of access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON into a custom struct or class, for example

```
struct Currency {
    let abbrev : String
    var value : Double
    var myCurrency : Bool

    var dictionaryRepresentation : [String:Any] {
        return ["abbrev" : abbrev, "value" : value, "myCurrency" : myCurrency]
    }
}

var currencies = [Currency]()
```

The `abbrev` member is a constant (`let`), the other members are variables.

```
...

       // Try to create an array out of the extracted data content.
       let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]

        if let rates = jsonResult["rates"] as? [String:Double] {
            for (abbrev, value) in rates {
                let myCurrency = abbrev == "USD"
                currencies.append(Currency(abbrev: abbrev, value: value, myCurrency: myCurrency))
            }
        }
```

The code uses native `Dictionary`. And `.mutableContainers` is useless in Swift anyway.

Comment: Alright, so after I create this global Array `currencies`, then append the value extracted into the variable `myCurrency`, how does that get added to the database? I understand how to get this data into my Xcode project, but then how do I put some other data back into the database itself?

Comment: I didn't get that you want to write the object back to the server. Well after changing the data you need to map the array back to JSON and an web interface to receive and process the data.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my question. I don't know how to turn the data back into JSON form and send it back to the database.

Comment: Your question is only about *edit ... received from .. database*. It doesn't mention at all to send the data back.

Comment: I edited my question to further explain. If you have another explanation for me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Add a computed variable `dictionaryRepresentation` to the struct to return a dictionary ( I updated the answer). Then map the `currencies` array to its dictionary representation and serialize it with `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject...` and send it to the server.